# Parallelization with AWS Glue DynamicFrames and ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, threadpoolexecutor

So I have been trying to explode AWS Glue jobs parallelization features. This is the approach that I have been following:

1. Reading data from the Glue DataCatalog with `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` into DynamicFrames
2. Creating transformations function to process these DynamicFrames.
3. Using ThreadPoolExecutor to run the transformations in parallel (code example below)

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    output_dfs = executor.map(transform_func, dynamic_df)
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'DynamicFrame' object is not iterable

I tried also converting the *DynamicFrame* to a PySpark dataframe using the `.toDF()` method (see: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-toDF](https://stackoverflow.com)) before passing it to executor.map, but `toDF()` must be part of the transformation I want to parallelize (I had found that running this method is way to slow outside, so I want to include it inside the body of `transform_func`)

My question is: How can we parallelize a DynamicFrame i.e. pass it as executor.map() arguments?

Comment: Why are you handling the parallelization yourself? Given that this is pyspark, Spark does the parallelization for you already.

Comment: My Glue Job was not fully optimized and took too long to run. Pyspark has very good parallelization features when there are clear partitions when you work with RDD. This was not my case, as I was not in charge of creating the datasets in the data lake (so I had to deal with a poor architecture from scratch). Along with that, I wanted another level of parallelization in order to read, transform and write several tables in parallel (not only partitions within a table).